# Pages per second

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

We are comparing the results(performance metrics) from Visual studio and JMeter to show it to the managers in the process moving from Visual Studio to JMeter tool.

if someone can help us to find out how to calculate pages per second in JMeter , that can be easily found in Visual studio reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Transactions Per Second chart of the JMeter's [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

[image]

or go for the equivalent [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listener which can be installed as a part of **3 Basic Graphs** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/):

[image]